# The Abbasid ransom for the Black Stone (Hajar Aswad)

Tags: middle-ages, middle-east, islamic-history

The [Black Stone (Al Hajaru Al Aswad, popularly called Hajar Aswad)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Stone) of the Kaaba in Mecca was stolen in 930 AD by the Qarmatians, and was returned 23 years later in 952 AD for "a huge" ransom paid by the Abbasids.

Does anyone know what that ransom amount was?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly, the book *[The eclipse of the 'Abbasid caliphate; original chronicles of the fourth Islamic century](https://archive.org/details/eclipseofabbasid05ameduoft/page/130)*, contains a slightly different account, suggesting that a huge ransom of fifty thousand dinars was offered, but never actually paid:

> In this year the Qarmatians restored the Black Stone to its place in the Sacred House of Meccah. It had been taken thence by Abu Tahir Sulaiman b. Hasan Jannabi. Bachkam had offered for its restoration fifty thousand dinars, but his offer had been declined, with the message: *We took it by order, and when an order comes to  restore it, we shall do so*. When Dhu'l-Qa'dah of this year came (began April 11, 951) the brothers of Abu Tahir wrote a letter wherein they stated that they were  restoring the Stone by the order of him by whose command they had removed it, that the ceremonies of the pilgrims might be performed completely. The person who brought it was Abu Mohammed Ibn Sanbar, who presently took it to Meccah, and restored it to its place.

---

The account was written in the book *The Experiences of the Nations*  by [Ibn Miskawayh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miskawayh) in the tenth century, so is an almost contemporary source writing closer in time to the events he was describing than [Al-Juwayni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Juwayni), who was the source cited in the Wikipedia article in the question..

Comment: Amazing find ! Thanks ! OMG, Sempaiscuba to the rescue again ! The expert on so many things I see, not just Ancient Egypt ! Much obliged

Comment: Very kind, but I'm hardly an expert.  Jack of all, Master of none, perhaps.  ;-)

Comment: Much obliged as ever, kind Sir